# instamojo throwing ERROR: Failed to resolve: in.juspay:godel:0.6.25.4.1423 for sdk 28

Tags: android, instamojo

I am getting the issue for applying instamojo in sdk 28. Its throwing ERROR: Failed to resolve: in.juspay:godel:0.6.25.4.1423

```
implementation 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:3.2.0'
```

and

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you added below one in project level build.gradle file

```
mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
    }
```

Remove and add it in application build.gradle file at parent level.
Then incluce

```
implementation 'com.instamojo:android-sdk:3.2.0'
```

in dependencies section.